# How to explain the ripple in this graph?

Tags: filter-design, phase

[image]

Hi everyone I need your help to understand this phase response would you please share your ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The phase response has not been fully unwrapped. See, for example, matlab's [`unwrap` function.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html)

The issue is the phase is a continuous function, but it has probably been extracted from a complex number using the arctangent.  Even the [`atan2` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2.html) in matlab only returns a number between -180$^\circ$ and +180$^\circ$.

After application of the `unwrap` function, the phase response will look much better and not exhibit as many "ripples".

For more explanation, see [this question and its answers.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/28221/80)